# Trouble with iOS production version, developer version works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, mapbox, dev-to-production

I have an iOS App, it takes data from server, and showing on map (using `mapbox`).
So, I have developer version in my mac, which I run on my iPhone, and it works well. But my production version from AppStore does not work same.
Trouble with some action in my `MapBoxViewController`, production version shows area at coordinates 0.000000 0.000000.
I knowing explored my code, and it looks like, in that moment, `MapBoxViewController` doesn't have some objects from `Core Data`.
So how can debug this feature without NSLog?

Both version (developer and production):
has same code,
has same `mapbox` token,
has same `mapbox` style,
has same data,
has same server,
has same actions with map.

And I have another action with same `MapBoxViewController` and it works well on both version with same `predicate` in `Core Data`.

Any idea?

Comment: In your production version you ask the GPS for a position. This can take several seconds during which the coordinate is undefined and will default to (0,0) until a good fix is received. Are you trying to use the coordinate straight after asking the GPS to give a position? In the Simulator, this delay will not be realistic and a valid coordinate can be returned quicker than on a phone.

Comment: @Magnas I have -(MGLCoordinateBounds)calculateBoundsWithArray:(NSArray*) coordinates, which calculate coordinate several objects, it seems there is no any object, in case I run production version from AppStore.

Comment: Can you show your MapBoxViewController code? Maybe then the problem will show itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a breakpoint in class you have the mapbox and run in on an iphone in debug mode connected to your mac.

Comment: When I run app from XCODE, everything works fine. So, I don 't see any mistake.

Comment: but I don't have any crash on my production version